# Set-Location : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '7' in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I tried to go to another directory using windows 10 powershell.
It's located in my E:\SEMESTER 7 directory.
But, when I typed on my windows powershell
cd semester 7 it always gives me an error. I tried with another directory file which is not contain number on it,and it worked.
How do I make it work for directory file that contains number?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When directory name has spaces, use single or double quotes: `cd "semester 7"` or `cd 'semester 7'`.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: I would say `Set-Location -Path "semester 7"`, _(if you wish to use aliases, then `sl "semester 7"`)_, or `Set-Location -LiteralPath 'semester 7'`, _(using aliases, `sl -l 'semester 7'`)_.

Comment: @vonPryz - StackExchange (all sites) generally discourages answering questions in the comments. Please propose your comment as an Answer.

Comment: The answers to the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983406/unable-to-move-forward-using-cd) explain why _quoting_ a path that contains spaces passed as an argument to `Set-Location` (one of whose built-in aliases is `cd`) is necessary .

Answer (score 0):

Tab completion finishes it this way:

```
cd '.\semester 7\'
```